# Custom View GI Navigation

Tags: acumatica

I'm having an issue with navigation in a GI that references a custom view.

I have a custom view and associated DAC created and used in a GI.  When I add navigation links to the GI it always does the navigation using the values in the first row of the grid.

I have another custom view where the navigation works fine.

I assume it has to do with having key fields defined in the DAC, but I do have IsKey assigned to several fields in the DAC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have PXPrimaryGraph set on the dac as a class attribute?

Comment: Also, can you confirm that those IsKey fields are identifying a unique record on your SQL View? Are all key fields from the navigation entry screen set properly on the Navigation Tab?

Comment: @Brendan No I don't have a PXPrimaryGraph set.  Could you provide an example of that.  My SQL view is joining a lot of different tables, I'm not sure what I would use as the primary graph.

Comment: @cbetabeta I believe the combination of the fields I have marked as IsKey are unique, I will confirm that.  For the Navigation setup in this case I'm just trying to link to the stock items screen.  I'm selecting the InventoryCD fiels and mapping that field from my view

Comment: If you search for PXPrimaryGraph in stackoverflow you will find many posts. Here is the Acumatica help: https://help-2020r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1dceb511-4e98-3700-7d7f-231688a7ac74

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you might not have a PXPrimaryGraph configured. This link should show you a few examples of setting one up.
https://help-2020r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1dceb511-4e98-3700-7d7f-231688a7ac74